# What's the purpose of RepeaterView in Xamarin Forms Labs?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

From the [sourcecode](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Controls/RepeaterView.cs) it seems that [RepeaterView](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/RepeaterView) is a wrapper above StackLayout, without any cell recycling.

If so, what's the purpose of using it instead of ListView which has similar API?

Comment: It's faster if you don't need to scroll and you are using static list of data.

Comment: faster in terms of performance, or in terms of development time? I'm afraid it could be easily misused in a places with lots of data..

Comment: In terms of perfomance. Of course it's not for big number of items.